# MacOs BigSur 11.1 Display Flickering

Tags: display, hdmi, big-sur

Since I have updated my Mac on the newest version of MacOS BigSur 11.1 my external monitor HP Z27n G2 starts flickering heavily in 2560 x 1440 resolution.

Now I have changed the resolution to 2048 x 1152 and it seems to be okay.

Now actually I would like to have the better resolution because the monitor can it and before the update it wasn't a problem.

Does anyone have the same issue and have a better solution then going down in resolution?

Thanks in Advance